# Получить url средствами php

Tags: php, url

Как получить полный url текущей станицы средствами php включающий # ?

Пример:

```
mysite.com#=mydata
```

Answer (score 3):

Часть после # - называется "URL хеш". Хеш работает только для браузера - т.е. для клиентской части. До сервера он не доставляется. Поэтому - нет, невозможно без очень сильных шаманств: используйте другую часть запроса для передачи на бекенд. Есть [аналогичный вопроc на большом SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby).

Answer (score 1):

Средствами php часть пути после # получить нельзя. Можно получить из JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

### Относительный адрес к странице в сети

```
<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>
```

Пример:

```
/razmestit-zakaz/?bitrix_include_areas=Y&clear_cache=Y
```

---

### Домен

```
<?=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>
```

Пример:

```
example.com
```

---

### Url (Полный адрес страницы в сети)

```
<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?>
```

Пример:

```
https://example.com/razmestit-zakaz/?bitrix_include_areas=Y&clear_cache=Y
```

---

### Абсолютный путь к сайту от корневой директории сервера

```
<?=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];?>
```

Пример:

```
/home/bitrix/ext_www/example.com
```

---

### Абсолютный адрес файла страницы на сервере

```
<?=$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];?>
```

Пример:

```
/home/bitrix/ext_www/example.com/razmestit-zakaz/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$main = curl_init("https://site.ru/page.html");
curl_setopt($main, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($main, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.7.62 Version/11.01');
$personal = curl_exec($main);
curl_close($main);
```

Только так и получится страница целиком, только часть получить невозможно. Вырежьте её регуляркой из всей страницы.